# How to maintain filtered child on an Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, tree

I've three tables:
Area
Region
Country

***Area*** has a OneToMany relationship with ***Region*** and 
***Region*** has a OneTo Many relationship with ***Country***.

i need to build a tree with only determinated country.

Example:
this is the full tree

```
         0   -> Area
       / | \
      1  2  3  -> Region
    /  \ | / \
   4   5 6 7  8  -> Country
```

i have to filter this tree starting with countries 4-6-7, like this:

```
         0
       / | \
      1  2  3
    /    |  / 
   4     6 7
```

the jpql query for gettig the Areas with this countries is pretty simple. But Unfortunately when i use the getter method for Region/Countries, he returns all the Region/Country. There's a way to get ONLY the filtered Region/Country that i need using JPA?

Comment: No there is no way to filter the data with JPA.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Hibernate you can try to use filters.

```
class Area {
    @OneToMany(...)
    @Filter(name = "regionFilter")  
    Set<Region> regions = new HashSet<Region>();
}

@FilterDef(name = "regionFilter", 
    defaultCondition = "country.id = :countryId",
    parameters = {@ParamDef(name = nameParameter, type = typeParameter)})
class Region {
}
```

To enable filtering in current Hibernate Session you should enable this filter and put required parameters in it:

```
session.enableFilter("regionFilter")
session.getEnabledFilter("regionFilter").setParameter("countryId", value);
```